# How to programmatically check if the current user has permissions to a site collection?

Tags: development

Given the URL of a site collection root, plus the current logged in user, I need to know if the user has permissions to at least see the welcome page.

If there is no Welcome Page set, then I need to programmatically check if the user has at least read permission to the site.

Comment: Duplicate question. See answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244037/check-current-users-permission-if-the-user-has-no-enumerate-permission-in-share)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Miguel, there is an existing question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244037/check-current-users-permission-if-the-user-has-no-enumerate-permission-in-share) which has a couple of good answers. (Can't migrate it unfortunately).

Answer (score -3):

From the Site collection

Go to Site Settings --> Site Permissions

click check permissions from the ribbon and type in the user

Comment: Assuming you are using Sharepoint 2010 and above. (which is reasonable, but thought I would add it anyway).

Comment: loool!!! by code!!!

Comment: In fairness, you didn't say that in your question. How about editing the question to make it clear you are looking for a code solution?

Comment: Indeed, but its tagged as development :)